# VS 2012 - Class Diagram - Properties from Fields?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm having trouble expressing what I need and that has made googling difficult. VS 2012 and I have a class diagram. Is there an automated way to create my properties from my fields (or vice-versa)? The encapsulation almost gets me there but a little too simplistic. I'm looking for it to create a section like

```
private int _projectID;
public int ProjectID
{
get{
return _projectID;
}
set{
_projectID=value;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# has auto-implemented properties.  As long as you don't need to access the underlying field elsewhere, you can use them.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384054.aspx

You can do

```
public int ProjectID { get; set; }
```

And it will automatically generate a field behind the scenes, but not with a name that you can access.

I don't understand the class diagram part of your question though, so this could be way off.